# angular 6 input type=date binding result into string

Tags: angular

I have a date input control

```
<input placeholder="Start" matInput ([ngModel])="data.startDate" type="date"> </mat-form-field>
```

The input control shows the material time picker. But when I change the date then the model is updated with a string value

model:

```
export interface IDate {
    rate?: number | null;
    startDate?: Date | null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Material datepicker works correctly with dates

Use:

```
<input placeholder="Start" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [ngModel]="data.startDate" (dateChange)="data.startDate=$event.value"  >
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```